# flutter playing a video from an asset

Tags: flutter, dart

when I'm trying to play a video saved in my assets I'm getting an error:
this is the initialize of the asset code:

```
@override
  void initState() {
  _controller = VideoPlayerController.asset("videos/main_animation_one.mp4");
  _initializeVideoPlayerFuture = _controller.initialize();
  super.initState();
  }
```

this is my pubspec.yaml:

```
assets:
- assets/images/
- assets/videos/
- assets/sounds/
```

a picture of the error:
[image]

playing a video from the network worked.
thank you!

Comment: have you tried the full asset path? "assets/videos/main_animation_one.mp4"?

Comment: Yes I have tried, it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using this PR:
https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/3123
hopefully they will merge it soon.